# Custom created website on Wordpress: MENU DISAPPEARED

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, hidden

Our domain name is Planetinfocus.org, we're a non-profit who had their website created a few years ago.

The main navigation bar/menu has recently gone missing, and no one has touched to previously.

If anyone here has had a similar experience in the past, it would be fantastic to hear your story and some tips.

We had tried to contact the creators of our site, but before we could even tell them about the issue, they quoted us for "customer service". Considering we are struggling with finances, we cannot afford paying them for an inquiry.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Find your **style.css** file and find line **99** it should read something like this:

```
#menu
{
   float: right;
   margin: 14px 30px 0 0;    
}
```

Change it to this:

```
#menu
{
   display: block;
   float: right;
   margin: 14px 30px 0 0;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1000;
}
```

If you find my answer useful accept it by clicking "check mark" on the left side of my answer.